# Are X and Y independent on these points?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Choose one of the points $(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$. at random. Let X be the first coordinate and Y the second, are they independent?

I'm assuming they are since each point doesn't affect the outcome of the next point.

Since they have the same possible outcome of $\frac{1}{4}$. Then:

$P(Y=0)=P(Y=0|X=0)$

$P(Y=0)=P(Y=0|X=-1)$

$P(Y=1)=P(Y=1|X=0)$

$P(Y=-1)=P(Y=-1|X=0)$

Am I heading on the right direction?

Comment: They are obviously dependent, compare $$P(X=0\mid Y=0)\qquad P(X=0)$$

Comment: No, not right, please reread what you wrote in your comment.

Comment: ((The OP erases their footprints, deleting the comments they posted.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They cannot be independent, since one is forced to be $0$ if the other one is not $0$.

We have : $P(X=1,Y=1)=0$

But on the other hand :
 $$P(X=1)P(Y=1)=P(X=1,Y=0) P(Y=1,X=0)=\frac 1 4 \times\frac 1 4 \neq 0$$

Comment: oh i see the combination now